# how do you deal with Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

i still new at coding, and i am wonder if anyone could help me with java code.

additionally, explaining how to deal with this issue.

here is my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1, number2, sum;
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: "); // prompt
        number1 = input.nextInt(); // read 1st number from user
        System.out.print("Enter second integer: "); // prompt
        number2 = input.nextInt(); // read 2nd number from user
        sum = number1 + number2;
        double average = (double) sum / 2;
        String message = "Sum is";
        System.out.printf("%s %d\n", message, sum);
        System.out.printf("Average is %.2f\n", average);
    } // end main method
} // end class SumAverage
```

Comment: this code compiles and runs without problem, so this is not the code that contains the problem you seem to be having.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code which causes the issue. Also include the complete error message.

Comment: This exception usually occurs when using more than one `new Scanner(System.in)` and calling `close()` on one of those scanners because that closes `System.in` for all of them.

Comment: @Stultuske man you sure is running );

Comment: @ThomasKläger so what do i need to do avoid that ?

Comment: @ASA since I copy-pasted it and executed it, yes.